# How can I split or read Factor variable containing numbers or numbers and letters?

Tags: r

I have a variable in my data containing numbers and numbers with letters, for example :

```
401, 405, 405-T, 102A.....
```

and I want to select for manipulation with my data only those values with numbers or numbers with letters. Does someone have an idea how I can do it ? I am a novice in r programming.

Answer (score 1):

We can get the logical index of elements that have only numeric characters (`[0-9]+`) from start (`^`) to end (`$`) using `grep`.  Use this index to `split` the vector ('v1') to get the output in a `list`

```
split(v1,  grepl('^[0-9]+$', v1))
#$`FALSE`
#[1] "405-T" "102A" 

#$`TRUE`
#[1] "401" "405"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("401", "405", "405-T", "102A")
```

Comment: It does not seem to work,,,which package i have to install for this  ?

Comment: split(only06$Tenant.private.name,  grepl('^[0-9]+$',only06$Tenant.private.name))
$`FALSE`

Comment: It is `base R` no external packages are needed

Comment: Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘grep’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)

Comment: @kenar  I am also using R 3.2.2, but I don't have that warning as `?grep` is a base R function

Comment: @kenar I am using just R console.  I don't know how things are working on r-studio.  Can you try it on R console

Comment: Warning message:
package ‘grep’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)

Comment: @kenar It could be a case where the RStudio is saving its environment each time.   One possible remedy would be to uncheck `Restore .RData`. i.e. click on  `Tools -> Global Options -> uncheck the "Restore .RData into workspace at startup" box or change  `Save workspace to .RData on exit` to `Never`.